# How can I replicate `fortune > /etc/motd` with systemd/tmpfiles.d?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

None of the action types described in [tmpfiles.d(5)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html) seems to allow for running a command as part of creating a temporary file.  It is possible to write an argument to a file, for example with action 'w', but not run `fortune > /etc/motd`.

Since the recommended way to generate tmp files in Arch Linux is tmpfiles.d, I figure there's a way to do it without resorting to systemd/rc.local hacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a normal `.service` unit and make it run on boot.

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "fortune > /etc/motd"
```

There is no special method for that; writing dynamic contents into a config file is out of scope for *tmpfiles.d*.